# How update relation fiels in DjangoRestFramework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I recently began to learn DRF library, I do not understand how in [this](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers) example make method update in AlbumSerializer to save foreign key.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What did you not understand in there... It's the basic example of a nested serializer??

Comment: in example there is a method of create but there is no method, update
how it make

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's basic example serializer, but if you need a suggestion, then this may help you. A simple update method for the serializer,

```
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    tracks = validated_data.pop('tracks')
    instance.album_name = validated_data.get('title', instance.album_name)
    instance.artist = validated_data.get('artist', instance.artist)
    instance.save()
    for track in tracks:
        new_track = Track.objects.get(album=instance, order=track['order'])
        new_track.title = track.get('title', new_track.title)
        new_track.duration = track.get('duration', new_track.duration)
        new_track.save()
    return instance
```

Comment: Thanks for the help